Matrix multiplication with 2nd matrix repeated
I'm trying to do matrix multiplication in torch. It goes like this
Operation 1
Shape of A -> 1,384
Shape of B -> 384,39000
Output shape -> 1, 39000

Shape of A -> 10,384
Shape of B -> 384,39000 --> Should be repeated 10 times as the value of 39000 x 384 should be the same while multiplying with all 10 of A
Output shape expected -> 10 x 39000

I need to repeat the "B" 10 times to get 10 x 384 x 39000 to use that to multiply with A.
How to do this?
If it's not possible, what's the best way to use multiprocessing to do operation 1 for all 10 instances? (10 is a random number I gave as an example, but in reality, this could go up to 100000 times). How to do this in torch?

...isn't this just how matrix multiplication works? What happens if you matrix multiply A and B?

@Vicki do you want 10 different instances of B getting multiplied to A, then you might want to check torch.vmap()

@SatyaPrakashDash you are a legend.VMAP works like a charm. Thanks.
